# How do you change a line in vim?

Tags: vim

Using `vim` I can change the word my cursor is on by tying `cw`. I can change the current character with `cl`. I can change everything inside some brackets with `ci{`.

I can even change the current and next line with `cj`. But how do I change just the line that the cursor is on?

I'm looking for something shorter or more efficient than one of these commands:
`ddko`, `0C`, `0Da`, etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is `S`, or `SHIFT-s`, as it changes the entire line regardless of the cursor location.

`cc` works similarly, but is arguably harder to type, with two consecutive non-home row key presses.

Answer (score 22):

To delete the current line and start insert mode, use `cc`. To change everything that comes after the cursor, use either `c$` or `C`

Comment: Ah of course! You think I would be able to deduce that having already known about `dd`. *facepalm*

Comment: Yep, `dd` is the corresponding command to delete a complete line.

Comment: Oddly enough I always use `dd`,`yy` or `C` but never thought about using `cc`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like either `^C` (or `cc`) (beginning of the line not counting whitespace) or `0C` (very beginning of the line) would work best.  Shift-c (capital c) means change everything from the cursor to the end of the line.